# Mapbox map not showing in ionic production build

Tags: reactjs, firebase, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, firebase-hosting

I am using ionic + react with the *react-mapbox-gl* library. Everything runs fine on localhost but when i deploy production build to firebase hosting, the website just returns a grey blank map.
I don't think there is a problem with the code, but I  cant pinpoint the problem.
I have tried changing the Mapbox token as well.

help appreciated :)

Comment: any error in console?

Comment: There are no errors in console related to mapbox i beleive.

Comment: I have the same problem and add this browserify settings works
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71006355/map-not-showing-in-mapbox

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the transpiler, this may be related to a known issue:

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/10173#issuecomment-753662795

Comment: Im gonna check it out since i havent any luck so far.